# An incapable perhaps coward child / man / woman who cannot deal with their problems and refers to their parents usually his / her mother

Tags: idioms

I was looking for an idiom / a word in dictionary to explain a child / man / woman who always tell's their problems to their parents because they are not quite capable to deal with their problems or because they are coward. I found one single idiom: *"mama’s baby"*!

This is exactly what we use in our language! The problem is that we can call both a child or an adult man / woman by this term. I have provided two separated examples which acknowledges that in both cases we use the same expression.

> **Example 1:**
>
> - Children are playing soccer in the yard and one of them gets a little hurt and goes to his mother and tell his friend on. When he comes back to his playmates, one of them calls him you're a **mama’s baby**!
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> - Imagine a wife and husband who have a quarrel and the they after their debate the wife's mom call's her groom and wants to talk to him and give some advice. Later the husband says to his wife: "Why you told the whole story to you mom? You are really a **mom’s baby**"

My question is that if it sounds natural in those scenarios to a native speaker's ear? If not, then please let me know what can I use as a replacement for the idiom?

Comment: mama's boy/wimp/crybaby/wuss  hey are you being paid to translate? Do I get a cut? :wink:

Comment: I agree with @Willow Rex; _mama's baby_ would only be used for a child; but _mama's boy_ can be used for an adult.

Comment: @J.R. what about if the adut would be a woman. Then I have to use "mama's girl"?

Comment: @A-friend - You could, but that is not quite so established as an idiom.

Comment: @J.R. Does it sound bizarre if I use mamma's boy for a girl?

Comment: @A-friend - If it were me, I'd use the less-familiar "mama's girl" rather than the less-fitting "mama's boy".

Comment: Is the precise idea you're trying to convey that someone whines about their problems always expecting someone else to solve them?

Comment: @TRomano wise question. Actually, yes! There is. This is perhaps because they cannot deal with their problems or contend their opponents or they are afraid of many things to be solved by them and so on and these all may be caused by their fear and weakness feelings. (There is nothing to do with psychological disorders; as it's clear, I'm more about an idiom which mostly in informal speeches would be expressed often to a child. It also can be attributed to an adult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mamma's baby" is not a phrase commonly used in English. You would more likely hear "mamma's boy" in the situation you described. A better and much more common term would be "tattletale", which would work for both of your examples. A few other words that might work:

- Snitch (slang for someone who reports others to the authorities, esp. with regard to illegal activity)
- Crybaby (general insult for  a whiner, also a good choice for your examples)
- Nark (British sp.)/Narc (American sp.) (slang for someone who reports others to the authorities, esp. with regard to illegal activity)

I guess I should just mention that all of these terms would be considered insulting schoolyard taunts.

Comment: I might explain the difference in nuance of each of your three suggestions a little. I spell narc with a "c" because I think it comes from "narcotics officer", but I wouldn't say the "k" is wrong. The word has definitely evolved to mean more than it used to.

Comment: There are lots of other interchangeable words for your suggestions like "rat" or even "sellout", but I am not looking for a noun for someone who tells somebody on. From among all these suggestions, I guess "Crybaby" fits the most because first, it is sexually neutral and then it can convey the message of referring to someone to complain either in the child case or the adult husband scenario. Do you agree? :) MadGab and @ColleenV

Comment: @ColleenV but the other question which comes to mind is that if "cry**baby**" is like "Mama's **baby**" which can be used only for children or it is another story here?

Comment: @A-friend I agree that crybaby is probably the best word for both examples, and probably the English equivalent of the phrase "mamma's baby" in your language. Hope that helps!

Comment: @A-friend - I'd say that _crybaby_ can work for children or adults, male or female. It means someone who is complaining about something a lot more than they should be.